# Azure Table Storage submitTransaction: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch exception

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-cli

I am trying to use the `DefaultAzureCredentials` to authenticate the `TableServiceClient` for  inserting entities into Azure Table Storage.

This is the code in my `Startup.cs`:

```
DefaultAzureCredentialOptions options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                Diagnostics =
                    {
                        LoggedHeaderNames = { ...},
                        IsLoggingContentEnabled = true,
                        IsTelemetryEnabled = true,
                        IsAccountIdentifierLoggingEnabled = true
                    },
                ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
                ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCredential = true,
                ExcludeWorkloadIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureDeveloperCliCredential = true,
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
            };

services.AddSingleton(new TableServiceClient(
            endpoint: new Uri(Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureTableStorage:Uri")),
            tokenCredential: new DefaultAzureCredential(options)));
```

The logs from the authentication look like this:

```
[Informational] Azure-Identity: DefaultAzureCredential credential selected: Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential
[Informational] Azure-Identity: DefaultAzureCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ]
```

I can add entities to the tables using the Azure CLI:

```
az storage entity insert --account-name oodledev --account-key xxxxx --table-name purchaseorder --entity PartitionKey=3 RowKey=CA, username=Sam
```

But when I try testing my C# application that inserts table rows, I get an exception:

```
tableClient.SubmitTransactionAsync(transactionActions);
```

> Exception thrown: 'Azure.Data.Tables.TableTransactionFailedException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: '0: this request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
> RequestId:f14fc64e-8002-0038-28f3-59a7ea000000
> Time:2024-02-07T18:26:01.3577039Z
> The index of the entity that caused the error can be found in FailedTransactionActionIndex.
> Status: 403 (Forbidden)
> ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Why can I insert rows from the CLI, but not from the C# application?

Comment: I think you shared your account key by mistake in the question. I have edited the question to remove it but please change your account key ASAP.

Comment: What are the RBAC roles you have on the storage account? You are not getting any errors in CLI because you are using account name/key to insert the data but that is not the case with your C# code. You should have [Storage Table Data Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-table-data-contributor) role assigned to you for your C# code to work.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I got my manager to add that role and it worked. He did not believe that could be causing the issue so I posted a question to confirm :).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add the Storage Table Data Contributor role for my user on Azure.
As @gaurav-mantri pointed out, the CLI uses the account name and key so it does not need that particular role in order to add items to Azure Tables.